# Scrapy Collecting Data From Table

Tags: python, scrapy

I dont get errors from the script below but this script returns no data. I am trying to get all the games for each of the weeks which start in table 4 in the html. When I enter the xpath commands in the scrapy shell I get data but once I put in the parse definition I dont get anything in return.

```
import scrapy


class NFLOddsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'NFLOdds'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sportsoddshistory.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.sportsoddshistory.com/nfl-game-season/?y=2022']

    def parse(self, response):
        
        for row in response.xpath('//table[@class="soh1"]//tbody/tr'):

            day = row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
            date = row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
            time = row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first()
            AtFav = row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first()
            favorite = row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first()
            score = row.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract_first()
            spread = row.xpath('td[7]//text()').extract_first()
            AtDog = row.xpath('td[8]//text()').extract_first()
            underdog = row.xpath('td[9]//text()').extract_first()
            OvUn = row.xpath('td[10]//text()').extract_first()
            notes = row.xpath('td[11]//text()').extract_first()
            week = row.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/table[4]/tbody/tr/td/h3').extract_first()

            oddsTable = {
                'day': day,
                'date': date,
                'time': time,
                'AtFav': AtFav,
                'favorite': favorite,
                'score': score,
                'spread': spread,
                'AtDog': AtDog,
                'underdog': underdog,
                'OvUn': OvUn,
                'notes': notes,
                'week' : week
            }
            yield oddsTable
```

Comment: I don't see any `table[@class="soh1"]` in the page. Either your xpath is wrong or you're trying to scrape the wrong page.

Comment: Its there I was able to get all the data from the scrapy shell with that command. But the entire rable name is-->
table class="soh1" onmouseover="changeto(event, &quot;#FFFFCC&quot;)" onmouseout="changeback(event, &quot;white&quot;)" (Sorry for late response was in hospital yesterday)

Comment: The class `soh1` does not exist on the linked page. Sure you're using the correct link?

Comment: Are you sure you did not mean to use https://www.sportsoddshistory.com/nfl-game-odds/ or some other specific URL and not the homepage?

Comment: @Ensar and at_SuoerUser you are both correct my apologies I should have looked at it more closely. I have changed the link in the question.

Comment: The example seems not complete. Where is the code which generates the `response`?

Comment: @kho this file is part of a scrapy project so the start_url is the link that gets passed into the response to generate the html variable. This code returns data but it returns the first table I need it to extract the 4th table that has all the weeks. Thank for your help!

Comment: The spider included in the question works perfectly for me, producing 335 items. So what are the problems you actually have with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating answer to include `Playoffs` table; code below

`scrapy runspider NFLOddsSpider.py -O output.csv` to execute

```py
import re
import scrapy

class NFLOddsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'NFLOdds'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sportsoddshistory.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.sportsoddshistory.com/nfl-game-season/?y=2022']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Find all H3 tags
        for h3 in response.xpath('//h3'):
            h3_text = h3.xpath('./text()').get().strip()

            # Find headings for Week/Playoffs tables
            if (m := re.match(r'(\d{4}) Regular Season - Week (\d{1,2})', h3_text)):
                # Week
                year = m.group(1)
                week = m.group(2)

                # Pick out the one TABLE that immediatelly follows the H3 header
                for tab in h3.xpath('.//following-sibling::table[1]'):
                    # Pick out the rows from that table
                    for row in tab.xpath('./tbody[1]/tr'):
                        yield {
                            'year': year,
                            'week': week,
                            'round': None,
                            'day': row.xpath('td[1]//text()').get(),
                            'date': row.xpath('td[2]//text()').get(),
                            'time_et': row.xpath('td[3]//text()').get(),
                            'fav_at': row.xpath('td[4]//text()').get(),
                            'favorite': row.xpath('td[5]//text()').get(),
                            'fav_cover_spread': bool(row.xpath('td[5]//a/b/text()').get()),
                            'score': row.xpath('td[6]//text()').get(),
                            'spread': row.xpath('td[7]//text()').get(),
                            'und_at': row.xpath('td[8]//text()').get(),
                            'underdog': row.xpath('td[9]//text()').get(),
                            'und_cover_spread': bool(row.xpath('td[9]//a/b/text()').get()),
                            'over_under': row.xpath('td[10]//text()').get(),
                            'notes': row.xpath('td[11]//text()').get()
                        }
            elif (m := re.match(r'(\d{4}) Playoffs', h3_text)):
                # Playoffs
                year = m.group(1)
                week = None

                # Pick out the one TABLE that immediatelly follows the H3 header
                for tab in h3.xpath('.//following-sibling::table[1]'):
                    # Pick out the rows from that table
                    for row in tab.xpath('./tbody[1]/tr'):
                        yield {
                            'year': year,
                            'week': week,
                            'round': row.xpath('td[1]//text()').get(),
                            'day': row.xpath('td[2]//text()').get(),
                            'date': row.xpath('td[3]//text()').get(),
                            'time_et': row.xpath('td[4]//text()').get(),
                            'fav_at': row.xpath('td[5]//text()').get(),
                            'favorite': row.xpath('td[6]//text()').get(),
                            'fav_cover_spread': bool(row.xpath('td[6]//a/b/text()').get()),
                            'score': row.xpath('td[7]//text()').get(),
                            'spread': row.xpath('td[8]//text()').get(),
                            'und_at': row.xpath('td[9]//text()').get(),
                            'underdog': row.xpath('td[10]//text()').get(),
                            'und_cover_spread': bool(row.xpath('td[10]//a/b/text()').get()),
                            'over_under': row.xpath('td[11]//text()').get(),
                            'notes': None
                        }
```

CSV data screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I got this data as well, but this in the first table. I need the 4th table on the page that has the weekly data Week1...Week18. The table you have is not the one I am looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My apologies I also had to fix the Start link as @Aleksandr poinyed out.

Comment: The data resides on this xpath //*[@id="content"]/div/table[4]/tbody. Full Path /html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/table[4]/tbody. But I cant seem to get to work with xpath

Comment: I only see two tables of data on the page  "View Odds by Team" and "View Odds by Season" - there is nothing in the entire HTML source that contains word "week" - are you sure that is the correct URL?

Comment: Week is the header its not in the table. I have made some goofs with the link so your question is fair. But yes this is the link:  https://www.sportsoddshistory.com/nfl-game-season/?y=2022. I am trying to collect 18 week tables

Comment: @LeoTorres made an update to answer based on the corrected URL - see above

Comment: This works just as you mentioned. But I need the Week Boxes at the bottom. There are 18 boxes with header like this "2022 Regular Season - Week 1" all the way to the bottom "2022 Playoffs" is the last box/table.

Comment: @LeoTorres - made another update - I think this is what you were looking for. I am not super familiar with football scoring/odds, but I think I grabbed everything. I think the @ signs indicate which home stadium the game was played - they might be better as boolean flags. Dates and times could probably be parsed and combined into a single field, etc.

Comment: YES, @Aleksandr this very close you got all 18 weeks. The only thing missing is the playoff table all they way at the bottom. How would you add that one? Think the if condition should have if "Playoff" condition.

Comment: This one has an extra column called "Round".

Comment: Added and updated code in the answer. Because they are slightly different formats - the `Playoffs` rows has `week` and `notes` columns set to None and `Week` rows has the `round` column set to None.

Answer (score 1):

After using `inspect_response` and debugging in scrapy shell, I found out the correct XPath to search. Unlike when you copy the path from browser, this path differs and I was only able to get it debugging with `inspect_response`:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response


class NFLOddsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "NFLOdds"
    allowed_domains = ["www.sportsoddshistory.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.sportsoddshistory.com/nfl-game-season/?y=2022"]

    def parse(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

This is the correct XPath to search for tables:
`"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/table[2]//table"`

This will give you 20 entries in a list; the first one is **2022 Results by Team**, and the last one is **2022 Playoffs** which you don't need so we have to exclude it:

```py
for table in response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/table[2]//table")[1:-1]:
```

Now you can extract the data as before using your code:

```py
for table in response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/table[2]//table")[1:-1]:
    for row in table.xpath("//tbody/tr"):
```

Here is the complete working class:

```py
class NFLOddsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "NFLOdds"
    allowed_domains = ["www.sportsoddshistory.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.sportsoddshistory.com/nfl-game-season/?y=2022"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for table in response.xpath(
            "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/table[2]//table"
        )[1:-1]:
            for row in table.xpath("//tbody/tr"):
                day = row.xpath("td[1]//text()").extract_first()
                date = row.xpath("td[2]//text()").extract_first()
                time = row.xpath("td[3]//text()").extract_first()
                AtFav = row.xpath("td[4]//text()").extract_first()
                favorite = row.xpath("td[5]//text()").extract_first()
                score = row.xpath("td[6]//text()").extract_first()
                spread = row.xpath("td[7]//text()").extract_first()
                AtDog = row.xpath("td[8]//text()").extract_first()
                underdog = row.xpath("td[9]//text()").extract_first()
                OvUn = row.xpath("td[10]//text()").extract_first()
                notes = row.xpath("td[11]//text()").extract_first()
                week = row.xpath(
                    '//*[@id="content"]/div/table[4]/tbody/tr/td/h3'
                ).extract_first()

                oddsTable = {
                    "day": day,
                    "date": date,
                    "time": time,
                    "AtFav": AtFav,
                    "favorite": favorite,
                    "score": score,
                    "spread": spread,
                    "AtDog": AtDog,
                    "underdog": underdog,
                    "OvUn": OvUn,
                    "notes": notes,
                    "week": week,
                }
                yield oddsTable
```

### References

- [printing 'response' from scrapy request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240802/printing-response-from-scrapy-request)